# Tag problem c# listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, tags

Hi i'm trying to use the tag item of a listbox.

heres my code.

```
            int number = 0;
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                Tag tag = (Tag) item.Tag;
                saveSlide(showid, tag.photoid, enumber);
                number++;
            }
```

problem im havin is when i run the program i get an error message sayin cannot convert type string to system.ListView but i haven't declared item as a string anywher in my program

This is where i add the items to the listbox. Please help. Im on a dead line and have sooo much more to do

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add selected item into listBox
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    Tag tag = new Tag();
    string title = drv["title"].ToString();
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(title);
    item.Tag = tag;
    tag.photoid = (int)drv["photoid"];

    listBox1.Items.Add(title);
}
```

Comment: This should be possible, can we where you add items to your listbox?

Comment: Can you post more code?  Which line number does it give you the error on?

Comment: Check that the designer has not added a string item to the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Poppy you are adding `title` to `listBox1.Items`.

`title` is of type `string`.

So when you access it use `string` type like this `foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)`.

Try. Does it help?

```
        int number = 0;
        foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            Tag tag = (Tag) item.Tag;
            saveSlide(showid, tag.photoid, enumber);
            number++;
        }
```

Comment: String doesn't have a tag property.

Comment: String does not have a Tag-Property.

Comment: I think `listBox1.Items` are of type `string`. Code in the loop might have other problems as you rightly pointed out.

Comment: ListBox.Items are an ObjectCollection.

Comment: Can they have with objects of type `string`?

Comment: Well it is an object, it could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

This works,  you need to show the code where you add items to the list:

```
private class Tag
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Tag";
    }
}

ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Tag = new Tag() });
foreach (ListViewItem item in listBox.Items)
{
    Tag tag = (Tag)item.Tag;
    Console.WriteLine(tag);
}
```

Edit following more code:

You are adding strings to your ListBox instead of the ListViewItem:

`listBox1.Items.Add(title);` should be `listBox1.Items.Add(item);`

Answer (score 1):

ListBox.Items is an [ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx). That means you can choose the kind of object to put in it.

When you're doing this:

```
string title = drv["title"].ToString();
listBox1.Items.Add(title);
```

you are putting string objects into it, so you would need to get them out like this:

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
```

Instead, you probably want your code to be more like this:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(title);
item.Tag = tag;
tag.photoid = (int)drv["photoid"];
listBox1.Items.Add(item); // The difference is here - add *item* not *title*
```

then you'll be able to use this the way you initially wrote it:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listBox1.Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does Tag has a member named photoid?  Maybe you need a cast in there to convert your 'tag' to whatever it's supposed to be?

```
        //Tag tag = (Tag) item.Tag;
        MyObject tag = (MyObject)item.Tag;
        saveSlide(showid, tag.photoid, enumber); 
        number++;
```

Comment: I'm guessing Tag is a class that Poppy has created - the cast is being done, as the Tag property just returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you named things weird I'd say the error is that you're trying to get a ListViewItem from a ListBox.

Comment: Might have been unnecessarily short. What I mean is that one of the objects in your ListBox is not (and can not be converted) to a ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last line of code of the second code-snippet and everything will be ok, which is as follows.

> listBox1.Items.Add(item);

**About the Error**

You added strings to the listBox as items and in the foreach an item(which is a string) is tried to convert(caste) to ListViewItem implicitly to  hich doesn't work and the compiler gives the error.

Hope it will work.